# How can i make scroll in a flexible div?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the div scrollable, with this block changing when the window is resized. The window itself should never be scrollable. The div should not be outside the window.

You can see an example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sampgx

Comment: Give a height to your div and use `overflow-y: scroll` CSS property

Answer (score 0):

You can define a fixed heigth to div, you can set this way:

```html
<div style="height:500px; overflow: scroll; background-color: green;padding: 10% 10% 0 10%">
    <!-- <div style="height:50vh; overflow: scroll; background-color: green;padding: 10% 10% 0 10%"> -->
    <ul style="font-size:30px">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzrjgy?file=src/app/app.component.html

I added class `listWrapper` for better understanding(you can remove it).
Just change the height of the wrapper with class `listWrapper` from 100% to 100vh.